# Proving that a sequence is convergent and finding its limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

If $x$ and $A$ are positive and $x_1 = \frac{1}{2}(x + A/x)$,$x_2 = \frac{1}{2}(x_1 + A/x_1)$, and
so forth, prove that the sequence $x_n$    is convergent and determine its limit.

Use your result to find an approximation to $\sqrt2$

My attempt:

To prove the convergence: I showed that since $x_n = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1} + A/x_{n-1}) \geq \sqrt{A}$ using the geometric-arithmetic inequality that $x_n$ is bounded below.

Then, I did $x_{n+1}-x_{n}=\frac{1}{2}(A/x_{n}-x_n) \leq 0 $ using the fact that $x_n \geq \sqrt{A} \space for \space all\space  n$

Which implies that $x_n$ is monotone decreasing. So we can conclude that it is convergent.

But how can I get an approximation of $\sqrt2$ using my result?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: If $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_n + A/x_n)$ for all $n$, and $x_n \to x$, then ... ?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me after the edit: Are you asking how to show that $x_n$ converges to $\sqrt 2$?

Comment: no, i have to find an approximation for $\sqrt2$ using my result that $x_n$ converges to $\sqrt A$

Comment: But  then each $x_n$ is an approximation for $\sqrt 2$ ...